# Xcode - WebKit Framework - "unlink" webview from Safari data

Tags: xcode, macos, browser, webview, webkit

I'm developing a small browser based on the WebKit framework of OS X (not iOS).
The problem is that the webview gets all data from Safari!
Example: I'm logged on Twitter in Safari. When I start my browser and I go to Twitter, I'm already logged in!

Comment: It's the cookies problem, where the webview shares the same cookies as Safari (And probably others like the HTML5 database).  Unfortunately I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes is a problem